# Trigger jQuery AJAX on Specific Button Click

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, forms, submit

Guys I have the following simple form:

```
<form action="?edit-form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="edit">
    <img src="test.jpg" alt="">
    <input type="submit" name="delete-image" value="Delete Image"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="Go" value="Go">
</form>
```

And this jQuery:

```
$(document).on('submit', '.edit', function(e) {
    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        type: $(this).attr('method'),
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function(html) { }
    });
    $("img").attr("src", "deleted.jpg");
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

The jQuery works great, except that I would like it to work only when the "delete-image" button is pressed, not when "Go" is pressed. How do I do this? Right now, the AJAX triggers on submit, I would like it to trigger when "delete-image" is clicked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your delete image button to a type="button" instead of type="submit" and give it a class or id:

```
<input type="button" name="delete-image" class="deleteImage" value="Delete Image">
```

The next step is to capture the click event like this:

```
 $(document).on('click', '.deleteImage', function(e) {
        //you want to start with blocking the default behavior:
        e.preventDefault();         

        $("img").attr("src", "deleted.jpg");
}
```

I don't think you need the ajax request here, as you are just manipulating the DOM, however this could be different depending on your actual requirements.

Comment: Thanks JanR, your code worked great. About the AJAX, I actually do need it since I'm also doing a MySQL query when the delete button is clicked (I'm dropping the image's filename from the db).

Answer (score 2):

Try to get out from the event handler when the `event.target` mismatches your requirement,

```
$(document).on('submit', '.edit', function(e) {
  if($(e.target).is('input[type=submit][name=Go]')) { return false; }
  //rest of your code
```